# Convert text into a list of its lines

Tags: python, list, function

My output from a function are all values that are broken on separate lines, I would like to turn this into a list.

```
The Score
Leon the Professional
Iron Man
```

I want to turn this into a list like:

```
movies= ['The Score', 'Leon the Professional', 'Iron Man']
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: By "output from a function", do you mean the function returns a string? or prints to stdout? or writes to file?

Comment: @Matthew Your example needs to be valid python otherwise we can only guess what you have.

Comment: Are we to assume that is the string `"The Score\nLeon the Professional\nIron Man"`?  Just use `s.split('\n')` and read the documentation...

Comment: It returns a string that is broken up on separate lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your input is a string.

```
>>> text = '''The Score
Leon the Professional
Iron Man'''
>>> text.splitlines()
['The Score', 'Leon the Professional', 'Iron Man']
```

More information on the [splitlines()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) function.

Comment: I should really use `splitlines()` more often. I'm always defaulting the plain ol' `split()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there is a reason to prefer `splitlines()` to `split('\n')`?

Comment: @mgilson Take a look at this [doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines)  for the answer -- I was curious too :)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Levon -- Ask a stupid question, get an obvious answer ("search the docs").  That's what I get for being lazy I guess ...  Thanks. (and quite interesting).

Comment: @mgilson I would also say that it must be better to use a function made for a specific use.

Comment: @jamylak -- but if they do the same thing, I'd prefer to only need to remember how to use 1 function than 2 ;-) ... I don't know about you, but my brain-space is limited.

Comment: It probably won't make much of a difference for small inputs but you can expect `splitlines()` to be more efficient when used on large datasets since it has been [specifically coded](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f691b32cc1fd/Objects/stringlib/split.h#l336) to split on newlines. I'll probable still use `split()` for noddy problems but it's good to keep in mind that special-case variants exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading lines from a file:

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    output = []
    for line in lines:
        output.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: `lines = map(str.strip, f)` is a shorter and more efficient way of doing this. The list comp version is: `lines = [line.strip() for line in f]`